# How to move string from QTextEdit to another QTextEdit using pushButton in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am using two Text Edit and two Push Buttons in between them. The objective is to list out the files from a particular folder in the first QTextEdit which is implemented successfully. Now I want to select particular file(s) and send them to the second QTextEdit using a pushButton in between them and in case, I want to delete file(s) the reverse should also happen with the second pushButton.

The following is the sample code of mainwindow.cpp:::

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDirIterator>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QTextCursor>
#include <QTextCharFormat>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QString>


QString dirPath;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushBrowse,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pushBrowseClicked()));
    connect(ui->pushAdd,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pushAddClicked));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::pushBrowseClicked()
{
    dirPath = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,"Choose a directory","/home",     

       QFileDialog::ShowDirsOnly);
    qDebug()<<dirPath;

    ui->textBrowse->setText(dirPath);
    display_button_target_files(dirPath);
}

void MainWindow::display_button_target_files(QString dirPath)
{
    qDebug()<<"[display_button_target_files]";
    qDebug()<<dirPath;

    int fileCount = 0;

    QDirIterator it(dirPath);

    ui->textDisplay->clear();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        it.next();
        QFileInfo fi = it.fileInfo();


       if (fi.isFile())
       {
            qDebug()<<it.fileName();
            ui->textDisplay->append(it.fileName());

           fileCount++;
       }
   }
  qDebug() << "Total file count: " + QString::number(fileCount);
  }
```

Comment: why you are using `QTextEdit`? Isn't `QListView` a better solution? You could use [QFileSystemModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qfilesystemmodel.html).

Comment: Thanks @MarekR for your suggestion. I've made use of QListWidget. It's working fine.